# Stored Procedure Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create this procedure in MySQL and show the error mentioned below.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `synctables`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
begin

insert into tdest
select s.keyval,s.val1,s.val2,s.val3 from tsource s left join tdest d 
on s.keyval = d.keyval where d.keyval is null;

declare finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
declare keyv decimal;
declare v1 decimal;
declare v2 decimal;
declare v3 decimal;

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR select s.* from tsource s inner join tdest d on s.keyval = d.keyval;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
open c1;

getvals: loop
fetch c1 into keyv,v1,v2,v3; 

if finished = 1 then
leave getvals;
end if;

update tdest set val1=@v1,val2=@v2,val3=@v3 where keyval=@keyv;

end loop getvals; 
close c1;

end
```

> Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   declare finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>   declare keyv decimal;
>   declare v1 decimal;
>   at line 13 */

When I delete this line the procedure is ok:

```
   insert into tdest
    select s.keyval,s.val1,s.val2,s.val3 from tsource s left join tdest d 
    on s.keyval = d.keyval where d.keyval is null;
```

Any ideas why the insert into is giving me an error?

Comment: The whole procedure can probably be replaced by a single multi-table `UPDATE` statement.  And it will run a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is particular about the order in which you do things in a `CREATE PROCEDURE/FUNCTION` statement. I'll be burned if I can find it in the docs right now, beyond a cursory mention under [`DECLARE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html), but the order ***MUST BE***

```
Header
Declare variables
Declare cursors
Declare handlers
Do actual stuff
```

With your `INSERT ... SELECT` in place, you're attempting to declare variables *after* you've begun "doing stuff", which isn't allowed. Move the `INSERT ... SELECT` *after* the last of your `DECLARE`s, and things should work much better.